# Recursive feature elimination and variable selection

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, rfe

How to get OA and Kappa value for each variable like this table in the figure below?
The study used RFE using Caret

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get this table if you do `rfe` on a dataset for classification. It looks like the article cleaned and renamed some column names but that is it.

```
library(caret)

data(mdrr)
mdrrDescr <- mdrrDescr[,-nearZeroVar(mdrrDescr)]
mdrrDescr <- mdrrDescr[, -findCorrelation(cor(mdrrDescr), .8)]

set.seed(1)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(mdrrClass, p = .75, list = FALSE)[,1]

train <- mdrrDescr[ inTrain, ]
test  <- mdrrDescr[-inTrain, ]
trainClass <- mdrrClass[ inTrain]
testClass  <- mdrrClass[-inTrain]

set.seed(2)
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,method = "cv",number = 5, verbose = FALSE)

rf_profile <- rfe(train, trainClass,
                  ntree = 50,
                  rfeControl = ctrl)
```

`rf_profile$results` contains the results that you can see in the table.

```
rf_profile$results
  Variables  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD   KappaSD
1         4 0.7355696 0.4599432 0.06290770 0.1274150
2         8 0.7934494 0.5736408 0.08328405 0.1725036
3        16 0.8060759 0.6011138 0.05961418 0.1222687
4        61 0.8260759 0.6411303 0.07101790 0.1483737
```

and if you want the names with those variables you can get them like this

```
rf_profile$optVariables[rf_profile$results$Variables]
[1] "VRA1"     "TI2"      "Xt"       "G.O..Cl."
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more clear. I have run the model and found the result table. I was wondering how this study found OA and Kappa value for individual variable.

Comment: @MSilvy, can you add the link to the study in your question? I have the feeling that the OA and Kappa are just the values that are in the result table

Comment: Sure-I dont know how to add the PDF, The study is this one: 
Ghosh, A., & Joshi, P. K. (2014). A comparison of selected classification algorithms for mapping bamboo patches in lower Gangetic plains using very high resolution WorldView 2 imagery. International Journal of Applied Earth Observation and Geoinformation, 26, 298-311.

Comment: Sure-I dont know how to add the PDF, The study is this one: 
Ghosh, A., & Joshi, P. K. (2014). A comparison of selected classification algorithms for mapping bamboo patches in lower Gangetic plains using very high resolution WorldView 2 imagery. International Journal of Applied Earth Observation and Geoinformation, 26, 298-311.